# GoError: Error: the method personal_newAccount does not exist/is not available at web3.js

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I just installed geth and
I start an instance of geth with this command: `geth --rinkeby --syncmode=light --http`
then I attach to that instance with this command: `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545`
and it seems to work well...

`personal` command return me that:
[image]

but on command `personal.newAccount()` I get this error:
[image]

From what I found in a old post: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/51772/account-created-using-web3-is-not-showing-in-geth-console I should allow personal api on starting command, but right now `--rpcapi personal` option is not available.

Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`--rpc.enabledeprecatedpersonal` geth command-line parameter helped me.